# Calling free() to release memory that is malloc(ed) by strdup() in multiple functions

Tags: c, pointers

Wrote a program TroubleTicket which allows the user to create a trouble ticket with various parameters. Code is using `struct ticket {}` to store ticket data. Each a new_ticket is added to `tkt_array`. The code is rather lengthy so I posted the relevant files and the code snippet. This is not a school project but a personal interest in learning some C.

Anyhow, there are functions, `create_ticket()` and `update_ticket()` which use `_strdup()` to handle user inputs. It's my understanding that `_strdup()` uses `malloc()` and this requires call to `free()` the memory. My approach is to call `free()` at program exit with the assumption that this will release malloc()ed memory. This task is done by function `free_tkt_arr()`.

The function `create_ticket()` uses `_strdup()` when setting `name`, `problem`, `assigned_to` and `status` pointers.

Function `update_ticket()` is also using `_strdup()` to update ticket `name`, `problem`, `assigned_to` and `status`.

Upon code exit, function `free_tkt_arr()` is called to release memory allocated by `_strdup()`.

What I'd like to know if calling `free_ticket()` on system exit releases all memory that was allocated by calls to `_strdup()` in `create_ticket()` and `update_ticket()`?

```
struct ticket {
    int priority;
    int number;
    char *name;
    char *problem;
    char *assigned_to;
    char *status;
};
```

The function `create_ticket()` uses `_strdup()` when setting `name`, `problem`, `assigned_to` and `status` pointers:

```
struct ticket tkt_array[NUM_TICKETS];

void create_ticket() {
    char *ptr;
    struct ticket new_ticket;
    printf("Enter your name: ");
    new_ticket.name = _strdup(get_input(20));
    printf("Enter problem description: ");
    new_ticket.problem = _strdup(get_input(100));
    printf("Assigned to: ");
    new_ticket.assigned_to = _strdup(get_input(20));
    //printf("Enter ticket status: ");
    //using _strdup() in case status is updated using _strdup which requires call to free()
    ptr = "new";
    new_ticket.status = _strdup(ptr);
}
```

Function `update_ticket()` is also using `_strdup()` to update ticket `name`, `problem`, `assigned_to` and `status`.

```
void update_ticket() {
    printf("Enter ticket number:  ");
    ptr = get_input(8);
    sscanf_s(ptr, "%d", &ticket_num);

    if (*ptr == '1') {
        printf("Updating Status.\n");
        printf("Enter Status update:  ");
        tmp_ticket2.status = _strdup(get_input(20));
    } else
    if (*ptr == '2') {
        printf("Updating Problem description.\n");
        printf("Enter Problem description update.  ");
        tmp_ticket2.problem = _strdup(get_input(100));
    } else
    if (*ptr == '3') {
        printf("Updating Assigned to.\n");
        printf("Enter Assigned to update.  ");
        tmp_ticket2.assigned_to = _strdup(get_input(20));
    }
}
```

function `free_tkt_array()` is called when exiting code and should be
freeing memory allocated by prior calls to `_strdup()`

```
void free_tkt_arr() {
    for (int i = 0; i <= tkt_count - 1; i++) {
        free(tkt_array[i].assigned_to);
        free(tkt_array[i].name);
        free(tkt_array[i].problem);
        free(tkt_array[i].status);
    }
}
```

> I thought about downloading and learning valgrind but maybe that's a bit over my head.

Comment: You can use `free` to deallocate every chunk allocated *that you still have a reference to*.  So if, for example, you replace a pointer to some allocated chunk (A) with a pointer to a newly allocated chunk (B) and don't have any other references to A, then you won't be able to free A after that replacement has been made.

Comment: Adding to what Scott said, if you're still unsure about memory leaks, you may run your program under valgrind. On Linux -> apt-get it-> run valgrind ./a.out.

Comment: "Thought about downloading and learning valgrind": Do it.  Especially in lower-level languages like C, debugging and sanitizing tools are absolutely essential.  Learning them may not be as exciting as bashing out code, but it's a way more valuable investment of your time early on.

Comment: "My approach is to call free() at program exit" -- don't bother.  Program exit will automatically free all memory allocated by malloc in the program.  You only need to call free when you're done with malloc'd memory and you want the program to continue running.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Nevertheless freeing memory before exit is good practice. A code may be reused later in different circumstances and lead to real memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you should free the string or not depends on what `get_input()` does. If `get_input()` returns a block of allocated memory, there is no need to call `strdup()`.

Note also that you should use `strdup()` instead of `_strdup()`:

- `_strdup()` is a Microsoft specific function that probably implements the same semantics as POSIX standard function `strdup()`.
- `strdup()` is available on Unix systems, specified in POSIX. It will be part of the upcoming C2x version of the C Standard (at last).
- if `strdup()` is not available on your system, you can either use a macro of define it this way:

  ```
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <string.h>

  char *strdup(const char *s) {
      size_t size = strlen(s) + 1;
      char *p = malloc(size);
      if (p) {
          return memcpy(p, s, size);
      } else {
          return p;
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can `free()` the memory, but you have **also** to assing `NULL` to the pointers, if you are not releasing the memory associated to the struct (which seems to be the case).  As you allocate in static global memory an array of structures, you will get all of them initialized to `NULL`, so no need to initialize pointers initially to check if they have been allocated.  But that doesn't hold after a while, so you have better to `memset(3)` or `bzero(3)` your structures, once you don't use them.  You don't show how do you distinguish a used record from an unused one, but if you are using a pointer field as a flag to mark it as unused, then you have to set it to `NULL` once you have released the ticket.  Lacking to do that, makes your pointers to continue pointing to unallocated memory (possible assigned by `malloc(3)` to other means, and a disastrous thing for your program)

You know, `free(ptr)` cannot make the pointer `ptr` to change to `NULL`, as every parameter is passed by value in C.  So, `free(ptr);`, followed by `ptr = NULL;` is a good bet.

BTW, having a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be fine to search for any other possible mistake.